# C# regex Split capture preceding characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

In C# i want to split a string into (substrings).

I'm trying to do this by using regex.split().

Every string has a header and some records after it
each new record can  be identified by certain keywords : CR  , STAT,EFFE 
(every identifier is 4 characters long, so CR has 2 whitespaces at the end
The thing is that i have to get 3 characters BEFORE the identifier which make it hard for me to make the regex. every

input:

```
123456 ;04;PERS;    ;073583118500CR;CR  ;PROF;09;30;073583118500;EFFE  ;PROF;0P
```

Desired output:

```
123456 ;
04;PERS;    !0735831185
00CR;CR  ;PROF;09;30;0735831185
00;EFFE  ;PROF;0P
```

What i've got so far is this regex pattern

```
(?=..;CR  ;|..;PERS;|..;EFFE;)
```

but i'm wandering if there isn't a cleaner way of writing this.
   something like:

```
..;(CR  |PERS|EFFE);
```

Comment: Your desired output does not match with your description.  Are you sure that is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to wrap the entire regex in a look ahead assertion

```
(?=..;(?:CR  |PERS|EFFE);)
```

See how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/zZ7lG4/1